# New user is assigned 2 roles: customer and superadmin

Tags: user-roles, hacked

I've a question about user role in WordPress.

After new user already registered. They can access with superadmin and customer role.

[image]

They can access to /wp-admin/, create blog, etc..

For my understanding, new user should get only 1 role, such as "customer".

I tried to investigate in my website. All user were assigned 2 roles: "customer" and "superadmin".

I think my website has been attacked by hacker.

[image]

How can I block them and how can I fix the user role issues.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

To restore super admin to just the `admin` username:

`<?php update_site_option( 'site_admins', array('admin') ); ?>`

Place a PHP file with this line in your `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` directory and access any site URL. Once done you can delete the file.

Alternative you can edit the `site_admins` key directly in the `wp_sitemeta` table (but the first is easier as it will be serialized data.)

You probably want to check your `default_role` options also, as well as checking for other user role and capabilities in case they have been changed too.